# Bit confused in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I am learning  mvc with ajax, js, jsp and jQuery.

I have a set of checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="clinical" id="clinical" name="clinical" value="0">
  <h6>Clinical Practice/Procedure</h6>
  <hr>
  <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentClassifId" name="incidentClassifId" value="0"></p>
  <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentViewIndex" name="incidentViewIndex" value="0"></p>
  <p><input type="hidden" id="appendStockistStatus" value="0"></p>
  <!-- <p><input type="hidden" name="clinical" id="clinical" value="0"></p> -->
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Documentation</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMiss" value="0">Missing Files</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalPol" value="0" > Policy not available</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMed" value="0" > Medical records unavailable</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalCon" value="0" > Confidentiality</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalProc" value="0">Procedures not followed</p>
  <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalVals" id="clinicalVals" value="0"></p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)" > Other (Specify)</p>
  <p><input type="text2" id="text" name="incidentClassClinicalVal"  disabled="disabled" style="width: 92%"></p>
</div>
```

When I click on checkboxes, its default value is changing from 0 to 1 i.e '0' is unchecked where as '1' is checked.
I am inserting this values in database MySql using MVC architecture and I am showing values to front end like:

This is my front end list values that are inserted in database:

[image]

"IncidentClassificationClinicalValue" column defines the values that are checked
If I selected only two checkboxes on click that eye button how to check that values with script

```
var incidentViewIndex = 0;
$("#incidentTable").on("click", ".view", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  save=1;
  //alert(save+"..view save");
  incidentViewIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
  $("#incidentViewIndex").val(incidentViewIndex);

  $("#successDiv").hide();
  $("#errorDiv").hide();

  var incidentClassifId = $(this).closest('tr').find(".incidentClassifId").val();
  alert("incidentClassifId = "+incidentClassifId);

  var clinical = $(this).closest('tr').find(".clinical").val();
  alert("clinical = "+clinical);
  var clinicalDoc = $(this).closest('tr').find(".clinicalDoc").val();
  alert("clinicalDoc = "+clinicalDoc);
  $('.clinicalCheck').prop('checked',true);

  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#incidentAdd"]').tab('show');
});
```

I tried this script but `$('.clinicalCheck').prop('checked',true);` is checking all checkboxes.

Comment: `$('.clinicalCheck')` returns a collection of all the elements having the class "clinicalCheck". So, yes, there all getting checked using the jQuery script you mention. **Do you have another question?** I guess yes... But it's unclear what.

Comment: @louys Patrice bessette can you tell me how to check the selected values

Comment: Just add the [`checked` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) the the inputs that has to be checked, using JSP, on server-side. EX: `<p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" checked>Documentation</p>` You have to fetch your MySql results to do it.

Comment: The value of a checkedbox is not limited to 0 or 1. It can be a string like "my value is Abracadabra"... But the checked or unchecked state is a boolean.